# SQL Totals grouped in a single column

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table like that [MainTable]:

```
Date        | Machine | Product | Scrap
---------------------------------------
2012-02-06  | M1      | P1      | 100 
2012-02-06  | M2      | P1      | 110 
2012-02-06  | M2      | P2      | 200 
2012-02-07  | M3      | P3      | 300
```

and I want to get a query that makes an output like that:

```
Type         | Total         | Scrap
------------------------------------
Machine      | M1            | 100
Machine      | M2            | 310
Machine      | M3            | 300
Product      | P1            | 210
Product      | P2            | 200
Product      | P3            | 300
Date         | 2012-02-06    | 410
Date         | 2012-02-07    | 300
Date-Machine | 2012-02-06 M2 | 310
```

My problem is that if I use UNION ALL to get the totals, the query lookup in to the [MainTable] a lot of times.
I want to calculate all the totals in a single lookup to improve the speed using the SQLite query instead of the java code.

I need this only in SQLite, not on another engine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with the Type, Total and Scrap columns and then insert the data you need with separate SQL statements like this:

step one: create a newTable with these columns: (type, total, scrap)

step two: run these statements:

```
INSERT INTO newTable 
SELECT "machine" as type, machine, sum(scrap) 
from yourFirstTable;

INSERT INTO newTable 
SELECT "product" as type, product, sum(scrap) 
from yourFirstTable;
```

or if you need these all in one query you could do something like this:

```
SELECT "machine" as type, machine, sum(scrap) 
from yourFirstTable
UNION
SELECT "product" as type, product, sum(scrap) 
from yourFirstTable
```

etc...

You can also join multiple times to same table and get same result like this:

```
SELECT TYPE, ITEM, sum(scrap) as sumTot
FROM   (SELECT "machine" as type, machine as item,  scrap from yourFirstTable) as A,
       (SELECT "machine" as type, product as item,  scrap) as B
GROUP BY TYPE, ITEM
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but in your examples you lookup into [yourFirstTable] a lot of times. My question is if is there a posibility to do the query with only one "FROM yourFirstTable". In your example you lookup into the table 4 times. (Edited)

Comment: I added a bit more to my answer.  Not sure if this will do what you need but it is another way to do it without a UNION.